# Why nothing is displayed on the frame?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

Seems every thing is correct but why nothing is displayed on the frame?
The drawBox method of the Box class is used to display the box on the screen.

```
class Box
{
    Graphics2D g2D;
    Box(Graphics2D g2D)
    {
        this.g2D=g2D;
    }
    void drawBox(int topx,int topy,int width,int height)
    {
        int _unitwidth=width/4;
        int _unitheight=height/4;
        g2D.setColor(new Color(252,82,86));
        g2D.fillRect(topx,topy,width,height);
    }
}
public class BoundedEnviron extends Frame
{
    public Graphics2D g2d;
    public BoundedEnviron()
    {
        super("Box");
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        g2d=(Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
        System.out.println(g2d);
    }
    public static void main(String $[])
    {
        BoundedEnviron be=new BoundedEnviron();
        Box b=new Box(be.g2d);
        b.drawBox(300,300,40,20);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and I saw a red box at the centre of the frame. What's wrong?

Comment: Well, this `g2d=(Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();` is bad idea to start with. Rather then guessing at how the API works, take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better idea of how the Api actually works and how you should work with it

Comment: @Sweeper for me nothing is displayed on the screen.

Comment: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) Follow the advice of @MadProgrammer. rather than the other advice. Keeping an instance of a `Graphics` object will have indeterminate results (e.g. showing the red box on one system / run, but not on another).